# Querying YouTube API for Channel Subscribers and Related Data

Tags: google-api, youtube-api

Can anyone provide information on whether there is an API available for YouTube that can be used to retrieve a channel's total number of subscribers as well as other related data?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [YouTube Data API v3](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3) [Channels: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list) endpoint with [`part=statistics`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/channels/list#part).